# SQL query "update" between 2 tables

Tags: sql, ssms

I have one database which contains two tables:

-`October2012_ID` which contains two columns:

```
a) OldId
b) NewId
```

-`BNP` which contains two columns also:

```
a)BankId
b)OrbId
```

I need to update the `BNP` table by replacing values contained into the two columns IF these values are available in the column `OldId` located into the table `October2012_ID`. And if this is the case, I need to update the columns in `BNP` by the value of `NewId`.

So:

```
Update BNP
SET BNP.**BankId**=October2012_Id.NewId
where BNP.**BankId**=October2012_Id.OldId and October2012_Id.**BankId** is not null
```

And also:

```
Update BNP
SET BNP.**OrbId**=October2012_Id.NewId
where BNP.**OrbId**=October2012_Id.OldId and October2012_Id.**OrbId** is not null
```

I'm a noob in SQL, so could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `or` between your conditions:

```
Update BNP
SET BNP.BankId=October2012_Id.NewId
from October2012_Id
where 
  (BNP.BankId=October2012_Id.OldId and October2012_Id.BankId is not null)
  or
  (BNP.OrbId=October2012_Id.OldId and October2012_Id.OrbId is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE BNP
   SET BNP.OrbId=October2012_Id.NewId
  FROM October2012_Id
  JOIN BNP.OrbId=October2012_Id.OldId  --The default JOIN is INNER. Just shorthand for INNER JOIN
 WHERE October2012_Id.OrbId IS NOT NULL
```

You just need to specify the table you'd like the values from using the `FROM` clause and `JOIN` onto the table you want to update.